# Hugo site, deployed to public/ directory in html, gives weird results

Tags: html, hugo, docsy

I have a Hugo site with lots of folders and subfolders, containing both `_index.md` files and many others. It uses the docsy theme.

Running `hugo server` displays the site correctly in the browser at localhost:1313

When I run `hugo` or `hugo -D` to get the same pages as HTML files on the disk, and I get

- a set of folders...
- ... containing only `index.html` and `index.xml` files,
- but no other files. All the other files are missing.
- links look like the raw .md file (example: `[VPAT](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/AccessibilityVPATS_allOS_en_HTML5/page/Content/accessibility.htm)`
- The index.html files are unstyled, unlike the pages generated by the `hugo server` command.
- I don't see how to use the `index.xml` files.

Here is an example of the files and folders produced by the `hugo` command:

```
public/
   index.html
   index.xml
   docs/
      index.html
      index.xml
      admin_intro/
         index.html
         index.xml
      troubleshooting/
         index.html
         index.xml
...
```

Here is what the .md file structure looks like

```
content/
   en/
      _index.html
      search.md
      docs/
         _index.md
         admin_intro/
            _index.md
            amdin_page_1.md
            amdin_page_2.md
            amdin_page_3.md
         troubleshooting/
            _index.md
            ts_page_1.md
            ts_page_2.md
            ts_page_3.md
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe your `postcss` process isn't running correctly. I had this problem after upgrading `Hugo` and `Docsy`

The `postcss` process isn't used in the `dev` mod (hugo server) but it is in `production` (hugo) so you will unfortunately get different results.

Try running `hugo` locally with the `--debug` flag and see if any errors show up.